# Getting the index of the min item on a list

Tags: python, list

I want to get the index of the  min item  on a list, but in case of a tie. I'd like to use the position of both min items and compare those position in another list.

```
order = [4, 1 ,2 ,1 ]
LPT = [20, 10, 5, 20]
new_order = []
```

I want to get the index from the min values in the order list and in case of a tie, use the max value from the same position in LPT.

`new_order` should be like this:

```
new_order = [3,1,2,0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a list-comprehension:

```
[x for x, _ in sorted(enumerate(zip(order, LPT)), key=lambda x: (x[1][0], -x[1][1]))]
```

**Code**:

```
order = [4, 1, 2, 1]
LPT = [20, 10, 5, 20]

new_order = [x for x, _ in sorted(enumerate(zip(order, LPT)), key=lambda x: (x[1][0], -x[1][1]))]
# [3, 1, 2, 0]
```

Comment: thank you so much, it's been very helpful. Sorry if i didn´t make myself clear, english is not my main language.